# Cyclic subgroups of finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let's say I want to list all the cyclic subgroups of $G$. Let's say $G = \mathbb{Z}^*_{10}$. Then I know all the elements in $G$ are $1, 3, 7, 9$ so all I need know is to find the cyclic subgroups from those elements. As I understand I need to find subgroups so that all elements generate from one element? Then if I'm right the subgroups are $\{1\}, \{3, 9\}, \{7\}, \{9\}$? Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier to note that $\,\Bbb Z_{10}^*\cong C_4=$ the cyclic group of order $\,4\,$, so that there are exactly

three subgroups here:

$$\{1\}\,,\,\,\{1,9\}\,,\,C_4$$

Check that $\,\{3\}\,,\,\{9\}\,$ cannot be subgroups as they don't contain the unit element...

Comment: ...and as a punishment you're going to upvote my answer now! :)

Comment: Already done :-)

Comment: what c4 means??what elements it contains?

Comment: baaa12 $C_4$ often is used to represent any cyclic group of order 4, all of which are isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_4, +)$.

Comment: @amWhy I guess i dont understand the calculation why 1,9 is subgroup?

Comment: @baaa12: $\,9^2=81=1\pmod {10}\,$ . In any group with an element $\,x\,$ of order two (an involution), the set $\,\{1,x\}\,$ is a subgroup (of order two, of course)

Answer (score 3):

Observe your "groups":
*A set cannot be a subgroup unless it also contains the identity element of the original group*!

Recall:

$H\le (G,*) \iff $:

$H$ is closed under $*$,

The identity of $G$ is IN $H$.

$H$ is closed under inversion. (For all $h \in H, h^{-1} \in H$).